# Why is the Levenshtein distance score so low for these two strings?

Tags: java, string, groovy, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison

I am using a Levenshtein distance algorithm to find similar strings and I  currently have my score for acceptance as 12 (because some of my strings have up to 5 words). But I was suprised to see the below two strings get a score of 11, they seem very different to me..

```
def string1 = "Facial Fuel"
def string2 = "Calendula Toner"

println("Result is ${distance(string1,string2)}");

def distance(String str1, String str2) {
   def dist = new int[str1.size() + 1][str2.size() + 1]
   (0..str1.size()).each { dist[it][0] = it }
   (0..str2.size()).each { dist[0][it] = it }

    (1..str1.size()).each { i ->
    (1..str2.size()).each { j ->
        dist[i][j] = [dist[i - 1][j] + 1, dist[i][j - 1] + 1, dist[i - 1][j - 1] + ((str1[i - 1] == str2[j - 1]) ? 0 : 1)].min()
       }
   }
   return dist[str1.size()][str2.size()]
}
```

Is something wrong with the algorithm here or is that the right score?

Comment: Do you have any unit tests for known distances? If not, that's the first thing you need to do (with *any* software development). For starters, take the Wikipedia page on this topic and use their examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is right.

```
    string1:   F a c i a     l   . F u   e l
    operation: S C S S S I I C I C S S I C S
    string2:   C a l e n d u l a . T o n e r
```

(`'.'` means `' '`)

Operations are

```
    C : Copy
    S : Substitue
    I : Insert
    D : Delete
```

Levenshtein distance is

```
    S * 7 + I * 4 = 11
```